# Detect Support for Notifications

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

I would like to detect support for the HTML5 Notifications API without throwing an error. I would prefer to be able to detect support synchronously, although using promises or a callback would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is window.Notification.

```js
if (window.Notification) {
  alert('support');
} else {
  alert('no support');
}
```

Here's a current list of browser support in case you want to know:
http://caniuse.com/#search=Notification

Comment: I'm not sure you need promises.  Here's an example to get you started on how you can do it without promises by having a fallback.   I'm not advocating the use of the plugin, but the example code on the site shows how to fallback. https://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/a-fallback-plugin-for-html5-web-notifications/